# Restarted httpd with Brew and now I get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, homebrew, macos-mojave

I had a successful installation of the brew formula httpd and I have been using it for a while now as my apache server. This hasn't been a problem until recently.

I tried to run httpd in the terminal, and I got this response:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 1 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf: 
Syntax error on line 117 of /usr/local/etc/httpd/modules.conf: 
Cannot load /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so into server: dlopen(/usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so, 10): 
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/icu4c/lib/libicui18n.63.dylib 
Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/php/lib/httpd/modules/libphp7.so\n  
Reason: image not found
```

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with the formulae php@7.1, so I ran `brew reinstall php@7.1`.

A gist I used.

https://gist.github.com/hgrimelid/703691ab48c4a4d0537cfe835b4d55a6